# How can I provide pre- and post-execution hooks for a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose I have a lambda function that cause side-effect and I would like to do some cleaning up once the execution fail ( I understand that Lambda function should not be designed/used in such a way but I believe Pre/Post execution hook is useful for many cases other than this).

Is there any way I can provide a pre- and post-execution hook to that Lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

1. Move all your code into a global try-catch-finally block, so you can
   handle internally in the lambda.
2. Add a Dead letter queue. If your lambda fails, it will move to dead letter queue and you can process the messages with another lambda.
3. Step functions with retry/catch blocks like this:

```
"SomeStep": {
   "Type": "Task",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:mylambda1",
    "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 3,
                "MaxAttempts": 2,
                "BackoffRate": 1
              }
             ],
     "Catch": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
                "Next": "StepFailed"
              }],
     "End": true
   }
```

Here is an example of a failed step, it just finishes with a message, but here you can add another function call.

```
   "StepFailed": {
     "Type": "Pass",
     "Result": "Process failed, but we ignore it.",
     "End": true
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambda does not support Pre/Post execution hooks.

If you need to do something pre or post execution you need to build a workflow to handle it.

There are a number of ways you could create a "pre or post execution hook" effect with Lambda. Take a look at [Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) and in particular, since you mentioned the execution failing, [How to Handle Errors in Serverless Applications with AWS Step Functions and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/handle-serverless-application-errors-step-functions-lambda/). Using Step Functions will allow you easily create a workflow to do something specific (ie the cleanup you mentioned) if a specific condition occurs (ie execution fails).

Answer (score 0):

Though AWS Lambda doesn't directly doesn't support the requested functionality, the same can be achieved by using third party libraries. One such libraries is [lambda-hooks](https://github.com/sweeetland/lambda-hooks/tree/master). Below is an example from their README

```js
const { useHooks, logEvent, parseEvent, handleUnexpectedError } = require('lambda-hooks')

// call useHooks with hooks to decorate your lambda with
const withHooks = useHooks({
    before: [logEvent, parseEvent],
    after: [],
    onError: [handleUnexpectedError],
})

const handler = async (event, context) => {
    // your lambda function...
}

// call withHooks passing in your lambda function
exports.handler = withHooks(handler)
```

One caveat with respect to `lambda-hooks` lib is that the handler function is expected to be async.

There is also another lib called [middy.js](https://middy.js.org/docs/intro/hooks) which provides similar functionality as one of their features.